# Group by Seconds for array of Timestamps

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of `timestamps` from my log data. I am trying to group these timestamps by `seconds` so that I can d
isplay in a charts for every 1 second.

```
[
   "2018-08-31T12:52:44.357174404+00:00",
   "2018-08-31T12:52:44.357133365+00:00",
   "2018-08-31T12:52:44.357185085+00:00", 
   "2018-08-31T12:52:44.357192810+00:00",
   "2018-08-31T12:52:40.197139820+00:00",
   "2018-08-31T12:52:40.197829400+00:00",
   ............
   ...........
   .........
   "2018-08-31T12:49:21.658622784+00:00",
   "2018-08-31T12:49:07.121419856+00:00"
]
```

Can somebody please let me know what could be the best possible way to group by `second` and displaying number of logs for every seconds.

Any help is appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: writing if statements could be a solution..., or creating another array of seconds and see when the seconds from original array match

Comment: what you mean by "group"? Want to separate every timestamp of each second in another array, in an object, or what?

Comment: @CalvinNunes exactly... :)

Comment: exactly what? an Array, an object or what?

Comment: @CalvinNunes array

Comment: @surazzarus added an answer that is an array holding objects with the second and all it's timestamps. Take a look, I think it is the best approach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I think you can go with the above approach, that I explain here:

1. Loop through `timestamps` you have, create a date of each one and get it's second.
2. Check if this second exists in a new array of timeStamps (that will be separated by seconds)
3. If it didn't find the second, then it creates a new object with this structure:
   `{Second: int, Times: []}` where `Second` is the "id" and `Times` is the array that holds all timestamps of that second.
4. If it finds the second in the new array, then it just push the timestamp to the object.

Then when you need to use the timestamps, you can run a loop in the `arrOfSeconds` and get the `arrOfSeconds[i].Times`

```js
let ts = [
   "2018-08-31T12:52:44.357174404+00:00",
   "2018-08-31T12:52:44.357133365+00:00",
   "2018-08-31T12:52:44.357185085+00:00", 
   "2018-08-31T12:52:44.357192810+00:00",
   "2018-08-31T12:52:40.197139820+00:00",
   "2018-08-31T12:52:40.197829400+00:00",
   "2018-08-31T12:49:21.658622784+00:00",
   "2018-08-31T12:49:07.121419856+00:00"
]
let arrOfSeconds = [];

for (var time of ts){
  let second = new Date(time).getSeconds();
  let index = arrOfSeconds.findIndex(a => a.Second == second);  
  
  if (index == -1){
    let obj= {}
    obj.Second = second;
    obj.Times = [];
    obj.Times.push(time);
    arrOfSeconds.push(obj);
  }else{  
    arrOfSeconds[index].Times.push(time)
  }
}

console.log(arrOfSeconds);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this way

```
var logArr = [
"2018-08-31T12:52:44.357174404+00:00",
"2018-08-31T12:52:44.357133365+00:00",
"2018-08-31T12:52:44.357185085+00:00", 
"2018-08-31T12:52:44.357192810+00:00",
"2018-08-31T12:52:40.197139820+00:00",
"2018-08-31T12:52:40.197829400+00:00"
]
var secondNumData = {}

logArr.forEach(item => {
    var itemSecond = item.slice(0, 19)
    if (secondNumData[itemSecond] == null) {
        secondNumData[itemSecond] = 0
    }
    secondNumData[itemSecond]++
})

console.log(secondNumData)
```

Answer (score 1):

You might need to compare the Dates in the UTC Format and then add them to a unique array. You can do that in the following manner.

```
function groupBySeconds(array)
    {   
        let bySeconds = [];
        array.forEach(date => {
           d = new Date(date);
           d = Math.floor(d.getTime()/(1000));
           bySeconds[d]= byday[d] || [];
           bySeconds[d].push(date);

        }
        return bySeconds;
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you could build the histogram output using `Array.prototype.reduce`:

```
const logs = [
  "2018-08-31T12:52:44.357174404+00:00",
  "2018-08-31T12:52:44.357133365+00:00",
  "2018-08-31T12:52:44.357185085+00:00", 
  "2018-08-31T12:52:44.357192810+00:00",
  "2018-08-31T12:52:40.197139820+00:00",
  "2018-08-31T12:52:40.197829400+00:00"
];
const seconds = logs.map(l => l.slice(0, 19));
const histogram = seconds.reduce((hist, val) => {
    hist[val] = (hist[val] || 0) + 1;
    return hist;
}, {});
console.log(histogram);
```